# Add 6 textboxes values into datagridview in 3 rows and 2 columns?

Tags: vb.net

I'm working on a project to calculate kitchen materials and when I put measures I have a lot of textboxes arranged 3 boxes each row.

But I can't complete code to transfer results as it's to datagridview down only one row filled but i want to transfer all these data first row second row.

Code I've tried is:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Dim ssql As String = "INSERT INTO kitchen (عدد,نوع) VALUES(@عدد,نوع)"
        command.Connection = con
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        command.CommandText = ssql
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("عدد", number.Text)
        '    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("عدد", number1.Text)
        '   command.Parameters.AddWithValue("عدد", number2.Text)
        '  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("نوع", kind.Text)
        '  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("نوع", kind1.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("نوع", kind2.Text)
        command.Parameters.AddWithValue("مقاس الالمونيوم", measure.Text)
        command.ExecuteNonQuery()
        RefreshData()
    End Sub
```

- Database : MS Access 2013
- Visual Studio 2013

Answer (score 0):

I changed database to sql server 2014 and it's done working perfect

insert into table statement working better on sql server